# Local behaviour of a family of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider a family of differential equations of the form $\dot{y} = F(y, s)$, where $s$ is a parameter. Is there any reference about the theory of such equations?

A more specific example: consider the partial differential equation $\partial y /\partial t - a x \partial y / \partial x + s \partial^2 y / \partial x^2 = 0$ (+ some boundary conditions). This is easy enough to solve for $s = 0$ (solution is $y(t,x) = y(0, x e^{at})$) and I am interested in local behaviour (ideally: asymptotic expansion) around $s = 0$. However, that value is obviously “singular” (putting quotes because I don't know the theory of such families and therefore don't have a definition for regularity, either). That is the kind of theory I'm interested in. Of course, stupidly googling “families of differential equations” does not help, because the Oracle seemingly knows only about families of *solutions* to differential equations. Does anyone have a lead?

Comment: The book "Introduction to Perturbation Methods" by Mark Holmes should have what you need. The topic that you were asking about is called singular perturbation theory, as Calvin already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fluent in the topic but I know some words to start: that problem is an example of a [singular perturbation problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_perturbation). A related topic is perhaps the idea of a matched asymptotic. Hope this helps.